# How clean mixed datatype in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of data with multiple columns and containing a column named 'weight' set to `VARCHAR` character type. It contains a mix of characters such as '400', '203.12', '602.35 grams', and NULL values.

Task is to clean and validate the entire column and set character type to float and replace missing data with average column weight to 2 decimal places.

I have the following CASE statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN weight LIKE ' grams' 
        THEN CAST(REPLACE(weight, ' grams', '') AS FLOAT) 
    WHEN weight LIKE ' g' 
        THEN CAST(REPLACE(weight, ' g', '') AS FLOAT) 
    WHEN weight IS NULL 
        THEN AVG(weight::FLOAT)  
    ELSE 
        weight::FlOAT
END AS validated_weight,
```

But it generates this error:

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "602.61 grams"

The expected column data output should set to float, 2 decimal places

I am using PostgreSQL 16 and learning SQL. Support required to resolve this error.

Comment: Have you read [the PostgreSQL docs on `LIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE)? You don't seem to have properly defined your wildcards using the `%` character. Instead, you seem to be inadvertently using `LIKE` in the same way as you would `=`. For instance, your first `CASE` condition should probably be `WHEN weight LIKE '% grams' THEN` to properly account for the fact that ` grams` appears after the value you're trying to retain.

Comment: Furthermore, you're conflating _types_ with [_dimensional analysis_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) (i.e. units) - in the context of RDBMSs, the term "mixed datatypes" will not usuall refers to mixing grams and ounces measurements.

Comment: Please do not change your question to a different one invalidating existing answers. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `CASE` expression with the following produces the described results:

```
CASE
  WHEN weight IS NULL THEN
    ROUND(AVG(REGEXP_REPLACE(weight,
                             '^((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))\s*(g(rams)?)?',
                             '\1')::NUMERIC) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL),
          2)::FLOAT
  ELSE
    REGEXP_REPLACE(weight,
                        '^((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))\s*(g(rams)?)?',
                        '\1')::FLOAT
END
```

This assumes that the input values are well formed.

Comment: Ah yes, the day is saved once again by unintelligible regex.  For OP, I find the Postgres documentation quite a handy resource to help me get a handle on what on earth I'm doing when resorting to use of regular expressions:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: An excellent resource for regular expression information is https://regular-expressions.info. I've found it to be an extremely valuable resource.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the like expression wrong. In order to be different from an equal expression you need to have at least one wildcard in the expression you compare to. Wildcards are `%` standing for multiple, possibly zero arbitrary characters and `_` standing for a single character.

So your expression should be

```sql
CASE
    WHEN weight LIKE '% grams' 
        THEN CAST(REPLACE(weight, ' grams', '') AS FLOAT) 
    WHEN weight LIKE '% g' 
        THEN CAST(REPLACE(weight, ' g', '') AS FLOAT) 
    WHEN weight IS NULL 
        THEN AVG(weight::FLOAT)  
    ELSE 
        weight::FlOAT
END AS validated_weight
```

Comment: This answer does not address the cause of the exception which occurs because of the expression `AVG(weight::FLOAT)`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. How do i resolve this?